# Static vs. Shared library for sharing RTOS library with third party (so without source code)

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I know similar questions have been asked, but it's still unclear to me.

I have written a library with multiple drivers and modules for Zephyr RTOS. Now I would like to share part of that library with a company, but not as source code. The idea is to compile the relevant source code for the specific hardware they have, and then share it. This way I can control for which products it's used, and of course I don't want to share my source code with them.

At first I have tried just sharing a static library, but that didn't compile for them. Shared libraries are not yet supported by Zephyr's CMake extensions, hence I haven't tried that yet. If it's the way to go I will dive into it.

What are my options? Shared library vs. static library (+ object files?)? What is recommended?

**More info**
Zephyr uses Device Trees. Hence, the drivers / modules I provide are compiled for a specific hardware target. I would like the company to provide me with the relevant hardware definitions so that I can provide them a pre-compiled library of my drivers/modules that works for their specific target. This library might have to be updated sometimes to include bugfixes / new functionality.

As the binaries are compiled with application + library, what would the trade-off be for Static vs. Shared library?

Answer (score 2):

I think shared libraries and header files is the way to go . As they offer advantages. Like smaller binary size and flexibility to update. You can find a nice description here.
https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

C++ recommends using shared libraries because it provides flexibility on Linux or Linux like systems
https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/libraries.php

Comment: Thank you. The firmware is compiled and updated as a whole, does that mean that the advantages of shared libraries then are less important? I think they would be combined into one big binary anyway? My goal is that I provide a library with the specific functionality they pay for, for only the specific hardware target they pay for. Zephyr uses Device Trees, which are compiled into the libraries before providing them. Do I need the flexibility of shared libraries?